# How do I create a keyboard shortcut to load nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

I want to set up a keyboard shortcut to load nautilus.  I have loaded the Keyboard Shortcuts program, and created a custom shortcut with the command `/usr/bin/nauilus`.  If I change this command to point to another application (e.g. `/usr/bin/gedit`) it works beautifully.  How do I get this to work for nautilus?

Comment: What kind of desktop environment do you use? What version of Ubuntu do you use? It works fine here in 11.04.

Comment: @htorque I'm using unity on 11.04 (Natty).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is already available the action *Home folder* tied to the shortcut <kbd>XF86HomePage</kbd>.

Change it to whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks - this works!  I'm interested to know why my custom launcher didn't work.

Comment: @tttppp: it seems to require a URI, so `nautilus /home/tttppp` should work

Answer (score 9):

1. press the start/super button on your keyboard
2. type in "system settings" without the quotes into the search box
3. select "system settings" to bring up the system settings window
4. select "keyboard" from the available settings
5. go to the "shortcuts" tab and click the plus button to add a new shortcut
6. in the name field, type something like "nautilus"
7. in the command field, type "nautilus /home/userName" without the quotes, where userName is the name of the logged on user. for example nautilus /home/samuel
8. after you apply, click to the right of your created shortcut, you should see new accerelator". then type your key combination (i used <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) for instance
9. there you go with your new shortcut key for nautilus

Comment: I have my nautilus shortcut set to `nautilus /home/lucas` on the key `Super+E` but it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Works on 18.04 with these trivial changes: `Settings` (not `System Settings`) and `Keyboard` in now in the `Devices` sub-section. An alternative to creating a new shortcut is to override `Launchers > Home folder` which worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You only need to tell `Nautilus` what directory it must open:

```
nautilus /home/yourusername
```

Notice you don't need to call `Nautilus` with its executable full path, but with the path you want to open (home in my case, but you can change it).

I linked it to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>.

You can create multiple variations of this, changing the path you want to open and setting different keys:

`nautilus /home/yourusername/Music Super+m` (to open your music folder)

`nautilus /home/yourusername/Images Super+i` (to open your images folder)

Comment: If nautilus is already open, it does not open a new window. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can write a script which just calls nautilus and assign that script using e.g. [Autokey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/).