# Create keyboard shortcut to open home folder (Nautilus)?

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, vmware

I'm running 12.04 inside VMWare Workstation.

I'd like to have the shortcut <kbd>Windows-E</kbd> to open my home directory (Nautilus). I tried it two ways, but none worked:

1. Going to `System Settings / Keyboard / Shortcuts / Launchers / Home Folder` I press <kbd>Windows-E</kbd> and it shows me `Super+E`, but when I press this key combination, I see a small text box in the lower right corner of my screen and the character `e` inside just typed (??)
2. Going to `System Settings / Keyboard / Shortcuts / Custom Shortcuts`, add a new one named "Nautilus" and command "nautilus", but has the same effect: records my keystrokes but opens this weird text box in the lower right

Executing `nautilus` from gnome-terminal works, but nothing else.

The other observation I made: I have <kbd>Windows+Down</kbd> to "restore" the current window. Even when I use this combination, which is custom and works for this action, I cannot open my Home folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Press and hold the *super key* for a while, see the icons on the launcher get numbered.The home folder always at top, so pressing *1* opens the nautilus home folder.

Comment: That will definitely do it, thanks! Still irritating that you can't map such simple action to your desired shortcuts.

Comment: Could you please see this link too.http://askubuntu.com/questions/58738/how-do-i-create-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-load-nautilus