# Keyboard shorcut for a custom folder in Desktop

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, customization

I would like to configure a keyboard shortcut for a particular folder in my Desktop. I will be using this folder quite often and is there a way to open them with a custom keyboard shortcut ?

The remote thing I came across regarding this is [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132557/create-keyboard-shortcut-to-open-home-folder-nautilus) which is for opening home folder similar to Windows, but I do not want to go to home folder and navigate from there all the way to a folder in the Desktop (mouse clicking the desktop folder is way too easier than this method).

So my Question: Can I have custom keyboard shortcuts for custom folders like folders in Desktop ? I'm using `12.04`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open any folder, file, or URL in its default application with the [`xdg-open`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xdg-open) command:

```
xdg-open '/home/palerdot/Desktop/My Folder'
```

Add that as a [custom keyboard shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/q/165286).